# CSV File opened using JS not showing the updated version of the file when replaced by another one with the same name. d3.csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Before everything is said, I've not much knowledge about using JS and especially not d3.csv. These are all code taken from a template from the internet.
Altho, I am pretty sure the problem lies within the file being saved in the Cache.

But for specificity's sake, I'm going to post the code.

On our page is a button that opens a table that takes it's values from the data in a CSV file.

This is the code in the HTML, the function which calls the script to view the table.

```
<script>
    $(".bar-tab").click(function() 
      {
        $.getScript("js/d3-bar.js"); 
      })
</script>
```

This is the "d3-bar.js" script itself.

```
!(function (d3) {

$("barcontent").empty();

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data/bar-data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  chart.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}
})(d3);
```

The problem with this is that when we replace the "bar-data.csv" file with another one, for we need to change it from time to time, it doesn't change. 
It changes when we manually clear the cache. Which brings us to what we think is the reason that causing the problem. Is there a way to bypass this? For the browser to not check the cache for the file we need?

Answer (score 2):

It's caching working like it's supposed to.

A quick way to do this is to just "bust the cache". This is normally done by adding useless query parameter to the url with a value that's always different on each request. Timestamps are good values for this. The browser will think the url is new, and it will request a fresh copy of it instead of the one it cached.

```
d3.csv(`data/bar-data.csv?t=${Date.now()}`, type, function(error, data) {
```

Alternatively, if you have access to server-side configuration, you can probably tell the server to tell the browser to not cache certain paths served. This would depend on the server software you're using though, so read their respective manuals.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this.

Comment: It works the first time but when I reload the page with the new file it still stops changing again. Does this mean I need to put the random GET request on the  $.getScript("js/d3-bar.js"); too?

Comment: @MarlXtianMonzonMarcera Inspect the Network tab in dev tools to see why it's loading the same file.

Comment: It says here that the Date.now() didn't actually work. Everytime I reload the page it loads the file "bar-data.csv?t=${Date.now()}", so I'm guessing it caches that and moves on, and when I reload, it checks for that file, and doesn't check the updated file. The Date.now() function didn't work, for some reason.

Comment: I wonder if I could just random a number using PHP, then echo than in the GET request. Let me try that real quick.

Comment: @MarlXtianMonzonMarcera The answer uses [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Note the use of backticks instead of quotes. If you use quotes, `'data/bar-data.csv?t=' + Date.now()`

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working! Thank you very much. More power to you! And I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. You can work around this by adding a random GET request after the file type like `"data/bar-data.csv?version=123"`

Comment: Thnx, I'm going to try this.